# XML file contents not showing on apache2 localhost when using SimpleXml function in PHP

Tags: php, xml, linux, apache, ubuntu

```
<?php
$bookxml =simplexml_load_file("book.xml");

print_r($bookxml);  
echo"Display this";

?>
```

---

xml file

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<book>
    <bookcode>COMPUTER</bookcode>
    <bookname>LEARN PHP</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Balguruswamy</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Arihant</publisher>
    <price>645.50</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>Maths</bookcode>
    <bookname>Solve Trig</bookname>
    <bookauthor>A.B.C</bookauthor>
    <publisher>TM</publisher>
    <price>150.42</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>English</bookcode>
    <bookname>Prose</bookname>
    <bookauthor>D .E.EF</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Vision</publisher>
    <price>64.65</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>COMPUTER</bookcode>
    <bookname>LEARN JAVA</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Balguruswamy</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Penguin</publisher>
    <price>424.9</price>
</book>
```

---

I can see the xml file when I run the php script in terminal using php filename.php but cannot see it when I try to do from apache localhost on my browser. What should I do ?

Edit:

When I open error log for apache2 I saw this.

> [Sun Jan 28 10:35:16.301835 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9407:tid
>   140581351434112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured --
>   resuming normal operations [Sun Jan 28 10:35:16.301914 2018]
>   [core:notice] [pid 9407:tid 140581351434112] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Sun Jan 28 10:47:21.326245 2018]
>   [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9407:tid 140581351434112] AH00491: caught
>   SIGTERM, shutting down [Sun Jan 28 10:47:22.379645 2018]
>   [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10070:tid 139652613879680] AH00489:
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun
>   Jan 28 10:47:22.379716 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10070:tid
>   139652613879680] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Sun Jan
>   28 10:47:25.835120 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10070:tid
>   139652613879680] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Sun Jan 28
>   10:47:26.887422 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10176:tid
>   140391800403840] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured --
>   resuming normal operations [Sun Jan 28 10:47:26.887537 2018]
>   [core:notice] [pid 10176:tid 140391800403840] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Sun Jan 28 10:47:30.516640 2018]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 10179:tid 140391718758144] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49064] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pushkarrao/Work/apachetrue/ [Sun Jan 28 10:47:30.631338 2018]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 10179:tid 140391701972736] [client
>   127.0.0.1:49064] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pushkarrao/Work/apachetrue/favicon.ico [Sun Jan 28
>   10:47:30.794247 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 10179:tid
>   140391710365440] [client 127.0.0.1:49064] AH01630: client denied by
>   server configuration: /home/pushkarrao/Work/apachetrue/favicon.ico
>   [Sun Jan 28 10:53:03.602646 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10176:tid
>   140391800403840] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Sun Jan 28
>   10:53:04.686297 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10534:tid
>   139701054691200] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured --
>   resuming normal operations [Sun Jan 28 10:53:04.686390 2018]
>   [core:notice] [pid 10534:tid 139701054691200] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Sun Jan 28 19:41:28.732489 2018]
>   [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10534:tid 139701054691200] AH00491: caught
>   SIGTERM, shutting down [Sun Jan 28 19:41:29.794682 2018]
>   [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13440:tid 139628059764608] AH00489:
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun
>   Jan 28 19:41:29.794753 2018] [core:notice] [pid 13440:tid
>   139628059764608] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: If you don't see the "Display this" then probably your script crashes. First thing to do is to check your http servers error log file, that is where php logs issues to. What does it say? Most likely a "File not found" due to a path issue...

Comment: Please add additional information to the question itself, not in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question, _use it_.

Comment: Well, you can tell yourself when looking through that log, various restarts, but nothing relevant.

Comment: Another guess: maybe all works fine, except that you output the actual xml which cannot be displayed by an html display program (a browser)? Check the page source you loaded into the browser.

Comment: Yeah. So what might be the problem ?

Comment: Well, do you see the "Display this"?

Comment: It displays the xml file just fine and I ran a few html pages too before this one. I doubt that is the issue

Comment: No. I cannot see "display this " too

Comment: Maybe you call the wrong script? Or look into the wrong error log file?

Comment: What do you mean by "it displays the xml file just fine"? Above you claim it is _not_ displayed.

Comment: What i mean to say that if I open the xml file directly into the browser. I can see it. But with php using simplexml I am not able to see it

Comment: `simplexml_load_file(...)`  will return a SimpleXMLFile object. You cannot simply output that using `print_r()`. That will either output something unexpected or crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml structure is not proper :

It should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>
    <bookcode>COMPUTER</bookcode>
    <bookname>LEARN PHP</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Balguruswamy</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Arihant</publisher>
    <price>645.50</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>Maths</bookcode>
    <bookname>Solve Trig</bookname>
    <bookauthor>A.B.C</bookauthor>
    <publisher>TM</publisher>
    <price>150.42</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>English</bookcode>
    <bookname>Prose</bookname>
    <bookauthor>D .E.EF</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Vision</publisher>
    <price>64.65</price>
</book>
<book>
    <bookcode>COMPUTER</bookcode>
    <bookname>LEARN JAVA</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Balguruswamy</bookauthor>
    <publisher>Penguin</publisher>
    <price>424.9</price>
</book>
</books>
```

your PHP code to get the xml elements :

```
<?php
     $bookxml =simplexml_load_file("book.xml");
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($bookxml);
?>
```